# Missing Template Rails on Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a jQuery script that looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/books/"+ mId,
  type: 'PUT',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { book: { description: bValue } },
}).done(function() {
  alert("DONE!");
});
```

In my routes, I have `resources :books`

In my book controller, I have the following:

```
def update
  @book = Book.find params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.update(book_params)
      format.json { render status: 200 }
    else
      format.json { render status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But for some reason, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template books/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just say `render`, you are rendering a view whose name is derived from the controller's and action's name. Such a view does not exist in your case, so you get an error.

An AJAX update should basically return no body, so you can just do

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 200
```

to avoid looking for the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return json message on 200 OK, you can simply do it like:

```
message = {'status' => 'Saved successfully.'}
render :json => message
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me as of Rails 6

`render plain: "OK"`